# A sack contains 50 marbles of 4 different colors.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A sack contains 50 marbles of 4 different colors. Then there is one color such that at
least n marbles are of that color. Find n

Comment: Can I say "there is one color such that at least one marble is of that color"?

Comment: I presume the question is: What is the highest number N, for which we can say with certainty that there are at least N marbles of the same colour in the sack.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more than $12$ marbles of each color, there would be no more than $12\cdot4=48$ marbles.. But if there are $13$ marbles of colors $A$ and $B$ and $12$ marbles of colors $C$ and $D$, there are $13+13+12+12=50$ marbles.

Comment: Yes. So I think the OP intended the answer to be $13$.